# Get the width of a div that was created in javascript using createElement

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using the javascript function createElement to create a div and then setting it's innerHTML.  After that is done I want to get the value for the width required to display the div with its full content.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

newDiv.innerHTML = "My new<br/>DIV";

// Get the width of the div here
```

I've tried the following:

```
Call                                      Result
--------------------------------------    -------------
newDiv.width                              undefined
newDiv.scrollWidth                        0
newDiv.clientWidth                        0
newDiv.offsetWidth                        0
newDiv.innerWidth                         undefined
newDiv.outerWidth                         undefined
newDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width      0
```

The javascript code to create the div is executed on an AJAX callback; I don't know if that has anything to do with the issue or not.

Comment: The `div` isn't in the DOM, so it has no height or width. You should add it before trying to get its width.

Comment: I can't directly.  This is happening on a autocompletion list.  It does get added to the list item but the result is the same.  But maybe I could add it to the DOM and then remove it an add it to the list as per usual?  I'll try it.

Comment: Maybe shadow DOM is a solution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the problem is that the element was just created, and not appended anywhere.

Follow this way -

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

Then, append to another element inside the HTML, let's say, body.

```js
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

And then, finally, use the command to measure

```js
newDiv.clientWidth
```

So, it should look something like this, if tried in console:

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
=> undefined

document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
=> <div>​</div>​

newDiv.clientWidth
=> 1281
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks.

And thanks to Treast too.